# How to put a box around atoms in ChemFig?

Tags: chemfig

How does one put a box around a group of atoms?

For example, I'm looking to put a box around the hydroxyl group with its bond (`--OH`) in the following molecule and can't seem to get any luck with the documentation or `fbox`. Any ideas?

```
\chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-OH}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TikZ masters surely can do this better but a basic idea is this: use `chemfig`'s `@{node name}` syntax for marking nodes and draw the rectangle afterwards using the specified nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-[@{b1,0}]O@{H}H}
\chemmove{
  \draw[-,red]
    (b1) -- ++(0,.25) -| (H.east)
    (b1) -- ++(0,-.25) -| (H.east) ;
}

\end{document}
```

[image]